# ASP.NET MVC Unknown Action when delete is pressed

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem, when I try to delete something, it gives me the following error message:

> "Error: Unknown Action"

This is my controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Staff")]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            string result = null;
            try
            {
                if (id == null)
                {
                    result = HIQResources.errorMessageUnknownAction;
                    return new JsonResult { Data = result };
                }

                StudentViewModel vm = new StudentViewModel();
                StudentDetail studentDetail = studentManager.GetStudentDetailById(id.Value);
                if (studentDetail == null)
                {
                    result = HIQResources.errorMessageUnknownRecord;
                    return new JsonResult { Data = result };
                }


              int deleteResult = studentManager.Delete(id.Value);

                if (deleteResult == 1)
                {
                    vm.Alert.SetSuccessMessage(HIQResources.messageOperationSuccess);
                    TempData["alert"] = vm.Alert;

                    result = HIQResources.messageOperationSuccess;
                    return new JsonResult { Data = result };
                }
                else
                {
                    vm.Alert.SetErrorMessage(HIQResources.errorMessageUnableToExecuteOperation);
                    TempData["alert"] = vm.Alert;


                    result = HIQResources.errorMessageUnableToExecuteOperation;
                    return new JsonResult { Data = result };
                }

            }
            catch (DbUpdateException ex)
            {
                Log.AddLogRecord(LogManager.LogType.Warning, LogManager.LogPriority.Low, LogManager.LogCategory.Teacher, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, base.GetLoggedUser());

                result = HIQResources.errorMessageUnableToDeleteRecord;
                return new JsonResult { Data = result };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.AddLogRecord(LogManager.LogType.Error, LogManager.LogPriority.High, LogManager.LogCategory.Inscription, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, base.GetLoggedUser());

                result = HIQResources.errorMessageExceptionOccurred;
                return new JsonResult { Data = result };
            }
        }
```

This is my Javascript:

```
 $('#ModalDeleteButton').on("click", function (e) {
                var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
                $.post("/Student/Delete/",
                    {
                        __RequestVerificationToken: token,
                        id: id
                    },
                    function (data) {
                        $('#myModal .close').click();
                        var baseurl = '@Url.Action("Index")';

                        var url = baseurl + "?message=" + data;
                        window.location.href = url;
                    });
            });
```

I would need more specific details on this error, it seems to me that the controller and the javascript is right, so I don't really know what possibly can be.

Comment: What's with those indents?

Comment: When you debug, I assume the controller action is not being hit?

Comment: Did your Delete action get hit? I think the parameter Id is null so your controller return this one result = HIQResources.errorMessageUnknownAction;
                    return new JsonResult { Data = result };

Comment: It is, but i had a value, I did a break point and it's not being read here:

int deleteResult = studentManager.Delete(id.Value);

                if (deleteResult == 1)
                {

The code is being jumped at this part, eventho the delete result has a value.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to call `$.post` then you need to put the `[HttpPost]` attribute above the method definition. Otherwise, it just assumes that method is actually a GET (which is why the action is "unknown")

EDIT:

Try changing your `$.post` to this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        __RequestVerificationToken: token,
        id: id
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#myModal .close').click();
        var baseurl = '@Url.Action("Index")';

        var url = baseurl + "?message=" + data;
        window.location.href = url;
    }
});
```

Comment: I forgot the to insert the [HttpPost] in the code, it has the [HttpPost].